# Using NamedTuple inside NamedTuple with Optional typing

Tags: python, oop, namedtuple

Is it possible to create `NamedTuple` inside `NamedTuple` like this?

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Optional
class BabyData(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int
    body_measurement: Optional[NamedTuple('height': List, 'weight': List)] = None
```

Thanks!

Comment: Type annotations don't "create" anything. They are a formal documentation.

Comment: Since you already have the code, you should be able to answer this yourself. Did it work? If yes, what's your question? If no, please expand it to a [mcve] including the error, and clarify why creating the type independently does not work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use `dataclasses` for this use case instead:

```py
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Measurements:

    height: list
    weight: list


@dataclass
class Baby:

    name: str
    age: int
    body: Optional[Measurements] = None
```

You can also have classes reference themselves:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:

    name: str
    age: int
    parent: Optional[Person] = None
```

Comment: FWIW, the exact same thing (separately declaring the types) can be done with NamedTuple.

Answer (score 1):

The example provided outputs an error at run time.

```sh
body_measurement: Optional[NamedTuple('height': List, 'weight': List)] = None
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To fix it you need

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List, Optional

class BabyData(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int
    body_measurement: Optional[
        NamedTuple("BodyMeasurement", [("height", List), ("weight", List)])
    ] = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    baby = BabyData(
        name="john", age=1, body_measurement={"height": [50, 51], "weight": [3, 3.5]}
    )
    print(baby)

# BabyData(name='john', age=1, body_measurement={'height': [50, 51], 'weight': [3, 3.5]})
```

In fact you try to mix two ways of defining `NamedTuple`. As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple).

```py
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
# This is equivalent to:

Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])
```

You should also consider using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses), see the [foxyblue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65651655/4413446).

Comment: Nice job for actually answering the question. I think I just avoided it

Comment: @foxyblue thanks I agree I do not think it's something to do, I think we collectively provided a good answer :-)